# Missing Callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function onRequest(req, res) {
    if (req.body.widget_name) {
        console.log(req.body.widget_name);
    }
    var fs = require('fs');
    var data = fs.readdir("corpdashboard/dashboards", 'UTF-8', function (err, files) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(data);
    });
    var body = req.body.dashboard_selected + ' ' + req.body.widget_selected + ' ';
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.setHeader('Content-Length', body.length);
    res.end(body);
}
exports.onrequest = onRequest;
```

I want to read  directories and the file in that so I write this code and run it. on running i am getting that fs:missing callback function :ENOENT readdir 'D:\dev\corpdashboboard\dashboard.js'
'D:\dev\corpdashboboard' is the where i have my ejs file and js file
what does it means? 
what should I do to read directories and files in them

Comment: [fs.readdir(path, callback)](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback)

Comment: Remove the second argument ('UTF-8').

Comment: If you expect other people to read your code, please indent it properly.

Answer (score 1):

From official spec: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback

```
fs.readdir(path, callback)
Asynchronous readdir(3). Reads the contents of a directory.
The callback gets two arguments (err, files) where files is
an array of the names of the files in the directory excluding '.' and '..'.
```

You are using wrong arguments. `fs.readdir()` does not take encoding. So `readdir` expects `path` which is a string and `callback` which is a function.

It should be:

```
var data = fs.readdir('corpdashboard/dashboards',function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
         return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A note to anyone reading this: The answers above **were** valid, but in Node v6.x, fs.readdir does accept an additional argument, which you can see in the documentation. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback

If you're encountering this issue, check to make sure that you're running Node v6.0.0 or later.

Comment: This should be a comment on the subject answer.

Comment: ^ I've not enough rep.